# Facing 'Unable to locate the CLI executable' on Windows

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile

I just installed Titanium and I'm not really familiar with this IDE. I added Android SDK to start my first application and everything looks cool until I tried to see my application in Android Emulator. I'm getting Unable to locate the CLI executable. *Please restart Studio or use Help > Check for Titanium Updates to install Titanium CLI.* and **Check for Titanium Updates** Says **No Titanium updates available**. and **restarting the studio** multiple times didn't work too. I cannot even preview my application in web browser. What am I doing wrong?

I'm using **Titanium Studio, build: 3.1.0.201304151600** on Windows Server 2008 R2 
Everything is up to date Node.js, Android SDKs, etc. 
I'm trying to create a web-based application frt Android 2.2+ and mobile web.

Comment: Did you succeed in fixing the issue?

Comment: I faced a similar issue which I solved by opening `cmd` and ran the following: `npm -g install acs` after that everything seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to 'Mukund Samant' with useful workarounds, I managed to fix this problem [although I faced another problem] by removing `node.js` and installing an older version (0.8.22) and then installing `node.acs` package manually by runnig this command: `npm -g install acs`. Now Titanium won't give me any errors or update messages on startup.

*Note that I found out I have to run Titanium Studio as Administrator!*

Comment: The crucial step being to run it as Admin.

Answer (score 3):

Farid,

There are several things you can try.

1.Type titanium in your command line and hit enter.If it gives 'not recognised as an internal or external command',it means Titanium package is not properly installed.

2.Try uninstalling just the Titanium node.js package using npm titanium uninstall command.

3.Once uninstalled,open Titanium studio.It will prompt you for installing Titanium CLI.Follow the steps and install Titanium CLI.

4.If these steps do not work,then uninstall node and install everything from the studio itself,rather than from the command line.

Sometimes installing Titanium CLI from command line fails.

EDIT:Before you try all this type node in your command prompt and see if node command is being recognised.If it is not you will have to set it to the PATH variable.

Comment: I'm stuck! I did uninstall and reinstalled titanium and node from scratch. now node is installed but when I open titanium it requests to download and install `node.js`, `node.acs`, `npm` and `cli` but at the end of installation it give me this error: `Setup encountered and error!`

Comment: manually setting the path of node.js in titanium didn't work too.

Comment: `node` and `npm` commands are registered at path variables and when I use `cmd` they work but I don't know what is wrong with Titanium!